# How to send email to Owners Group using Powershell

Tags: powershell, email, groups

I wanted to know how I can email, for example, a csv file to users who belong in the Owners group using PowerShell? I have found an example [here](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849925.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) and the code below is the sample provided:

```
Send-MailMessage [-To] <String[]> [-Subject] <String> [[-Body] <String> ] [[-SmtpServer] <String> ] -From <String> [-Attachments <String[]> ] [-Bcc <String[]> ] [-BodyAsHtml] [-Cc <String[]> ] [-Credential <PSCredential> ] [-DeliveryNotificationOption <DeliveryNotificationOptions> {None | OnSuccess | OnFailure | Delay | Never} ] [-Encoding <Encoding> ] [-Port <Int32> ] [-Priority <MailPriority> {Normal | Low | High} ] [-UseSsl] [ <CommonParameters>]
```

Can someone give me an example to of how to do so using the above or any other method? I would greatly appreciate it as I really need some assistance on this matter.

Comment: Do you have your smtp server address ?

Comment: Yes I do. Can you give me an example of how to incorporate it? Just an example so I know what values to plug in based on what you provide. Please advise.